# openfire chat server giving error while sending emoji's

Tags: ios, xmpp, chat, openfire

I found this error while sending the emojis in openfire chat application server. Please suggest how to solve it.

> Error Domain=GCDAsyncSocketErrorDomain Code=7 "Socket closed by remote
>   peer" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Socket closed by remote peer}

Answer (score 1):

Encode your messages with `NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding` and `NSUTF8StringEncoding`

```
 NSString *messageStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[textview.text UTF8String]];

 // encode message

 NSData *msgData = [textview dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
 NSString *goodMsg = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:msgData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
```

*Note: If your client app gets the emojis formated as \ue415 you can transform them afterwards with something like this:*

```
- (NSString *) substituteEmoticons {

    NSString *res = [self stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\ue415" withString:@":)"];
    res = [res stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\ue403" withString:@":("];
    res = [res stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\ue405" withString:@";-)"];
    res = [res stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\ue418" withString:@":-x"];
        .....
    return res;
}
```